# Where do Valérie and Harold go?

Tags: amsterdam

At the end of the movie Amsterdam, Valérie and Harold left for an unknown location, out of the Gestapo reach.

There is an hint given by Paul Canterbury, an MI6 spy. He talked about some birds related to the location they were heading.

Did someone get the bird name or know where they left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After watching this movie again, I get what Paul Canterbury said and it is:

> "Beautiful weather this time of year."

and

> "And the blue-headed vireo migration to boot."

From the [blue-headed vireo Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-headed_vireo), I found this map with, in blue, the hivernal distribution of the birds.

[image: Geographical distribution of Blue-headed vireo.]

This, with the fact the action takes place around January, leads to the conclusion that they are heading to a Central American country such as Mexico, Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras or Nicaragua.